# Supremum Proof Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose that $x_n \leq y_n, \forall n$. Show that $\sup x_n \leq \sup y_n$. I would like to prove this by contradiction but am slightly stuck as how to go about doing this.  I started off with sssuming that $$\sup x_n = x > \sup y_n = y.$$  Then we have that $\forall 0 < \epsilon < x - y$, $\exists N$ such that $\forall n \geq N$, we have $$0 < y - y_n < \epsilon < x - y.$$  I am stuck here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not quite. At least it doesn't to me

Comment: @MartinR limsup and sup are different, although I do think this is a duplicate of some other question.

Comment: single line proof: If $\sup  x_n>\sup y_n$ then $\sup y_n$ can not be an upper bound of $\{x_n\}$ so there is an $x_k>\sup y_n$. So $x_k>\sup y_n \ge y_k$. A contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $y-y_n$, consider $x-x_n$.

Then we have for some $N$:
$$0\le x-x_N<\epsilon<x-y$$

which gives $y<x_N$.

By definition of $\sup$, $y_n\le y \,\forall n$, and thus $y_N\le y<x_N$.

This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need contradiction.

We have $x_n \leq y_n$ for all $n$. Let $y^* = \sup_n y_n$. Then $y^* \geq y_n \geq x_n$ for all $n$. Let $x^* = \sup_n x_n$. Then the supremum is the least upper bound, so $x^* \geq x_n$ for all $n$ and if there is any other value $z$ so that $z \geq x_n$ for all $n$, then $z \geq x^*$. Notice $y^*$ fits the bill of $z$ here, so $x^* \leq y^*$.

Contradiction also works though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a completely alternative approach, but it can apply in more cases.

Suppose $X, Y \subset \mathbb{R}$ have the property that, for each $y \in Y$ there exists $x \in X$ with $x \geq y$. Suppose $\sup X \ne \sup Y$, and for contradiction assume that $\sup X < \sup Y$. Then we can fix $y \in Y$ with $\sup X < y \leq \sup Y$, and furthermore $x \in X$ satisfying $y \leq x$. But this means $\sup X < x$, a contradiction. Therefore, $\sup Y = \sup X$ or $\sup Y < \sup X$, which is a tedious way to say that $\sup Y \leq \sup X$.

Our case involves taking $X = \{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $Y = \{y_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Note that our property holds because for each $y_n \in Y$, $x_n \geq y_n$.

---

In fact, for any $X, Y \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\sup Y \leq \sup X$ if and only if the above holds.

Answer (score 0):

You have to *get* and understand what the definitions *mean* and develop an "yeah, that's obvious" sense  (and such an intuition can only come with practice and rereading and rereading the definitions and drawing lot of pictures).

single line proof:  If $\sup x_n > \sup y_n$ then $\sup y_n$ can not be an upper bound of $\{x_n\}$ so there is an $x_k > \sup y_n$.  So $x_k > \sup y_n \ge y_k$.  A contradiction.